# Elixir/Phoenix - Connect to external database

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

I connected the main database in the dev.exs and it works fine. But in my project I plan to use several databases. I know that in the file dev.exs can connect multiple databases but this option doesn’t suit me. Databases connections will be stored in the main project database. I want to know: how can I connect to different databases using the elixir code without using a file dev.exs?

Comment: I'm having a hard time picturing what you're asking. Are you asking if you can set up multiple Ecto repos, or if you can connect to a db dynamicaly with config only known at runtime?

Comment: Its second. I want to know how I can connect to new database at runtime (that is, when the Phoenix server is already running)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start multiple instances of your Repo with different connection options.

Then, use the [`Repo.put_dynamic_repo/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/3.2.5/Ecto.Repo.html#c:put_dynamic_repo/1) function to tell the Repo which of the databases should be used for queries in the current process. (The documentation for this function also tells you how to start more of the same repo).

There's also a discussion document that goes more in-depth about this topic: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/replicas-and-dynamic-repositories.html

Comment: Essentially, I need to connect to the database, execute the query, and disconnect from it. Then connect to another database, execute another query and disconnect from it. I do not need to prescribe settings for all databases in the configuration file.

Comment: Yeah, in that case you can start a repo dynamically, use `put_dynamic_query/1` and then execute your queries. After that, stop the repo using `Repo.stop`.

Comment: This section of the second link looks like it would be perfect for your use case: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/replicas-and-dynamic-repositories.html#dynamic-repositories I like the `Repo.with_dynamic_repo/2` idea